# How to include existing project as library in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010.
Problem:
I want to build project A, B and C. Project A and B are independent where C will use both of them as a library. I open three empty c++ projects. I build and compile project A and B with no errors.
Then I build project C with adding the exiting project function, adding additional include directories through Project->Property->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

After that, I finished building project C and then compile, following is the error I got.

Error:
LNK2019, LNK1120

I searched through the web and I belief that there should be some additional setting is need under the Project->Property->Linker...
But I am not sure what they are, anyone can help?

Comment: Actually you don't need to build 3 different projects separately. You can have one solution (in VS) with all three project within. But you still need to set correct include paths.

Comment: I want to separate them so that I can send project A or B to other people as a library.

Comment: @sflee you still can. The project files for libraries A and B can be completely independent of C. The *solution* file is what binds them together as dependencies, and also brings linking libraries from dependent projects as a bonus (which will solve your problem). Shipping A and B as stand-alone, either in source or bin format, has nothing to do with that. Johnny is correct.